# Need to make a List

Tags: android

Need to make a List that each line have Image and data (text)

what is the right way? with list of table row ? or it is possible with ListView?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

A ListView is the easiest if you don't know the length of the list, and/or you want it scrolling.

If you have a list and you want to control the height (e.g.: 1 page etc), you might not be the best off with a listview, but better take a relative- or linear layout, possibly in a scrollview (but then, if you have a scrollview, you probably stopped at listview ;)  )

Comment: Ok but in ListView it is possible to make put in each line an image and Data if yes how?

Comment: Well, a listview has a "getview" function, and that can return for instance a relativelayout with a textview and an image. Why don't you follow the listview manual, it's quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` is the way to go, it will take care of releasing the memory and it will be faster to draw and to process.

You can follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) in order to build the basic structure. Then modify the `list_item.xml` file (or however you named it) in order to fit your layout.
Then, use a custom adapter, you can extend `ArrayAdapter<item>`, for example, and there you can build the rows as needed

For example, you can have a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` aligned to the left, and the `TextView` in the right.
This layout is going to be reused in every row.

[This is a tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) that you can follow to create it.

If you feel like make it more efficient, watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA&feature=related) that can help you optimize your `ListView`.

I hope that helps.