# How to populate a ListView after setContentView() is called?

Tags: android, android-layout

My app is pretty simple with only two views.  The first is a login page.  Once you're logged in I call setContentView() to switch to the second view.

The second view contains a list with data to be fetched from a remote server after the view is displayed.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to populate the list when its containing view is displayed using setContentView().

Any suggestions on how to handle this or where to look?  Most of the examples I've seen suggest creating a class that extends ListActivity but then, how does that class get instantiated?

Comment: Refer my answer in this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080033/need-to-make-a-list/5080118#5080118 and refer my blog for a sample one http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/04/parsing-data-from-internet-and-creating.html , ping me if you have any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to switch to a ListviewActivity you don't use setContentView();
setContentView() is only used to load a new XML file containing a new view, or to load a view (i.e. a LinearLayout) containing the rest of your views.

To load the ListviewAcivity you need to use an intent.

Let's say you have your login activity: LoginActiviy.java, and you data activity (the ListviewAcitivity) DataActivity.java, then you load the data activity with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DataActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your DataActivity.java you use setContentView to load the view for that activity.
Also you use DataActivity.java to load the data from the server and show it on the screen.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

ListViews use an adapter to determine their contents.  Those adapters have some sort of data backing. Sometimes this is a Cursor from a local database, sometimes this is a static array of elements, and sometimes this is a mutable collection.  It sounds to me like you would like the data to be able to change.

Check out this post on how to create a ListView backed by a collection that can be changed:

[adding item to listView after passing info through an intent in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714456/add-item-to-listview-after-passing-info-through-an-intent-android/6714690#6714690)